# Django-Oscar URLs for Django 2.0?

Tags: python, django, url, django-oscar

Django-Oscar has apparently been updated to Django 2.0. I am new to Django, I am not sure how I would update the URLs that are mentioned in the [Oscar Tutorial](https://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.1/internals/getting_started.html):

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from oscar.app import application

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

    # The Django admin is not officially supported; expect breakage.
    # Nonetheless, it's often useful for debugging.
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'', include(application.urls)),
]
```

This is the url that is currently available:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

So, do this mean that I would change the django-oscar URls to?:

```
 path(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
```

Answer (score 2):

The documentation on readthedocs is out of date for some reason - here's the [most recent version](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/master/docs/source/internals/getting_started.rst#urls) on Github which provides configuration for Django 2.

To use `path` you need to remove the regular expression syntax in the URLs. The use of `include()` also has been dropped for url configs passed directly, so you end up with:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.contrib import admin
from oscar.app import application

urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', application.urls),
]
```

Comment: Thank you @solarissmoke. I appreciate this information. How long do you think it would take a beginner Django developer to get a django-oscar site up and running?

Comment: @newbee A non-customised django-oscar site should be relatively easy to setup even if a Django beginner. The challenge(s) lies in the customisation.

Comment: Thx for the answer! Is there a way to help `django-oscar` team to keep an up-to-date doc on `readthedocs`?

Answer (score 0):

Django oscar always put their URLs in their app directory's apps.py file and then include that URL's to project level urls.py file, that's the design decision for Django oscar. But I would recommend you use path() than url() as this will help you to avoid the complexity.

```
##django-oscar/src/oscar/apps/basket/apps.py    
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

from oscar.core.application import OscarConfig
from oscar.core.loading import get_class


class BasketConfig(OscarConfig):
    label = 'basket'
    name = 'oscar.apps.basket'
    verbose_name = _('Basket')

namespace = 'basket'

def ready(self):
    self.summary_view = get_class('basket.views', 'BasketView')
    self.saved_view = get_class('basket.views', 'SavedView')
    self.add_view = get_class('basket.views', 'BasketAddView')
    self.add_voucher_view = get_class('basket.views', 'VoucherAddView')
    self.remove_voucher_view = get_class('basket.views', 'VoucherRemoveView')

def get_urls(self):
    urls = [
        url(r'^$', self.summary_view.as_view(), name='summary'),
        url(r'^add/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', self.add_view.as_view(), name='add'),
        url(r'^vouchers/add/$', self.add_voucher_view.as_view(),
            name='vouchers-add'),
        url(r'^vouchers/(?P<pk>\d+)/remove/$',
            self.remove_voucher_view.as_view(), name='vouchers-remove'),
        url(r'^saved/$', login_required(self.saved_view.as_view()),
            name='saved'),
    ]
    return self.post_process_urls(urls)
```

then imported by project level config.py file

```
##django-oscar/src/oscar/config.py
# flake8: noqa, because URL syntax is more readable with long lines

from django.apps import apps
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView

from oscar.core.application import OscarConfig
from oscar.core.loading import get_class


class Shop(OscarConfig):
    name = 'oscar'

    def ready(self):
        from django.contrib.auth.forms import SetPasswordForm

        self.catalogue_app = apps.get_app_config('catalogue')
        self.customer_app = apps.get_app_config('customer')
        self.basket_app = apps.get_app_config('basket')
        self.checkout_app = apps.get_app_config('checkout')
        self.search_app = apps.get_app_config('search')
        self.dashboard_app = apps.get_app_config('dashboard')
        self.offer_app = apps.get_app_config('offer')

        self.password_reset_form = get_class('customer.forms', 'PasswordResetForm')
        self.set_password_form = SetPasswordForm

    def get_urls(self):
        from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

        from oscar.views.decorators import login_forbidden

        urls = [
            url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url=reverse_lazy('catalogue:index')), name='home'),
            url(r'^catalogue/', self.catalogue_app.urls),
            url(r'^basket/', self.basket_app.urls),
            url(r'^checkout/', self.checkout_app.urls),
            url(r'^accounts/', self.customer_app.urls),
            url(r'^search/', self.search_app.urls),
            url(r'^dashboard/', self.dashboard_app.urls),
            url(r'^offers/', self.offer_app.urls),

            # Password reset - as we're using Django's default view functions,
            # we can't namespace these urls as that prevents
            # the reverse function from working.
            url(r'^password-reset/$',
                login_forbidden(
                    auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(
                        form_class=self.password_reset_form,
                        success_url=reverse_lazy('password-reset-done'),
                        template_name='oscar/registration/password_reset_form.html'
                    )
                ),
                name='password-reset'),
            url(r'^password-reset/done/$',
                login_forbidden(auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(
                    template_name='oscar/registration/password_reset_done.html'
                )),
                name='password-reset-done'),
            url(r'^password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>.+)/$',
                login_forbidden(
                    auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
                        form_class=self.set_password_form,
                        success_url=reverse_lazy('password-reset-complete'),
                        template_name='oscar/registration/password_reset_confirm.html'
                    )
                ),
                name='password-reset-confirm'),
            url(r'^password-reset/complete/$',
                login_forbidden(auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(
                    template_name='oscar/registration/password_reset_complete.html'
                )),
                name='password-reset-complete'),
        ]
        return urls
```

Oscar's idea is to modularize every app. That's why it stores app's all url to apps.py in every app folder and include that to project level config.py file.